# How to put a Leaflet control outside?

Tags: leaflet, basemap

I want to know how can I set a "selector layer" (L.Control.Layers) outside the container in Leaflet. Like this screenshot of an OpenLayers application:

[image]

Comment: I see that you commented on my question, there is an answer that is working. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171970/ol3-boundless-layer-selector-placement?noredirect=1#comment455173_171970)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is like this:

Since you want to place it outside the map. you have to create a div and give it an id so that it can be called later.

1. Create a div e.g. `<div id='jpt'></div>` in the body of HTML and use css to position it.

   `<style>
       #jpt {
           position : absolute;
           top : 10px;
           right : 200px;
      }
   </style`

After that in the scripts

2. Initialize layer control. `c=L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays)` and then
3. Add to map `c.addTo(map)`
4. Append it to previous div `$('#jpt').append(c.onAdd(map))`

this will show 2 controls so

5. Hide Control inside map by adding `$('.leaflet-top.leaflet-right').hidden = true` at the end of script just before `</script>`

Comment: Still error. I don't know where I set the jquery code, where I referencing it, do your reply but I have error still...                                                  Thank you so much

Comment: Post your code in a jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BasiMontes/z70s44d7/

Comment: It is working, jsfiddle is reacting well.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know how can I set a "selector layer" (L.Control.Layers) outside the container in Leaflet, but I don't know how can do it

Comment: place a div ided jpt outside the map where you want to display the selector. the code will put selector in that div. the div can be positioned anywhere using css.

Comment: How? What jpt? I have changed the code. In this link ( https://jsfiddle.net/BasiMontes/z70s44d7/ ) doesn't appear jpt. Thank you so much for your reply

Comment: jpt is id of div,

Comment: I'm very confused. I don't understand you well. I'm somewhat saturated, could you give me an example of code? Thanks so much

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BasiMontes/spj2b0b2/ Nothing. Is it possible speaks by mail? basi_montes@hotmail.com